# Why Local Hotspot is closing when app is closed

Tags: android, hotspot

After API 26, android released [startLocalOnlyHotspot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#startLocalOnlyHotspot(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback,%2520android.os.Handler)) that starts a local hotspot.

I'm using this local hotspot for devices >=Oreo in my android app. The issue that I'm facing is that as long as the app is visible, it works fine but after the app is closed, the hotspot closes. There are some rare cases where the hotspot doesn't closes even after the app is not visible.
Here's the code I'm using to start the local hotspot.

```
 //Workaround to turn on hotspot for Oreo versions
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  public void turnOnHotspot() {
    if (!oreoenabled) {
      wifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(new WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
          super.onStarted(reservation);
          hotspotReservation = reservation;
          currentConfig = reservation.getWifiConfiguration();

          Log.v("DANG", "THE PASSWORD IS: "
              + currentConfig.preSharedKey
              + " \n SSID is : "
              + currentConfig.SSID);

          hotspotDetailsDialog();

          oreoenabled = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
          super.onStopped();
          Log.v("DANG", "Local Hotspot Stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(int reason) {
          super.onFailed(reason);
          Log.v("DANG", "Local Hotspot failed to start");
        }
      }, new Handler());
```

I've looked into logs but there's no clue why this is happening. Ideally, when hotspot is closed it should come into the `onStopped()` callback but it doesn't when app is closed(and hotspot turns itself off for no reason).

Comment: You should run it in a Thread

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the answer to my question.

Comment: If you say so, if it's not in a service/thread it will be killed as soon as the app is destroyed.

Comment: Yep, I did some research on this and I think you're right. I'm currently confused which option to go with. a simple thread/intent service/loader/view model. Seems like I need an intent service. What's your take on this?

Comment: Yes exactly, have a look at this project - https://github.com/aegis1980/WifiHotSpot/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/fitc/wifihotspot